# Apache Main DocumentRoot doesn't exist

Tags: apache, document-root

I'm trying to find where a reference to `/var/www/html` still exists in my Apache configuration. When I run `apache2ctl -S` it says `Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"`, but none of my virual hosts or my main Apache config file point to that directory.

I have tried searching all of the config files using `grep -r "var/www/html" /etc/apache2/` but it returns nothing.

There is no `<Directory>` entry for that path in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file (there is one for `/var/www`, under which I store the virtual hosts).

This configuration quirk bothers my OCD, but I also frequently see these entries in my Apache error log:

```
[Fri Jun 28 18:19:53.424619 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 22665] 
[client 209.222.82.167:47376] AH01276: Cannot serve directory
   /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex 
   (default.php,index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated
   directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

How does Apache decide what the main documentroot is, and how can I change it?

EDIT:

For my sites-available/sites-enabled, I have four files, `000-default.conf`, `000-default-le-ssl.conf`, `000-www-default.conf`, and `000-www-default-le-ssl.conf`. The `000-default.conf` is a redirect set by certbot to point to the https site and has no DocumentRoot directive. The `000-www-default.conf` is identical to `000-default.conf` but for the ServerName (one has www and the other doesn't); the same pattern follows for`000-www-default-le.conf` and `000-default-le.conf`.

Here is the output of some things I've tried:

- `apache2ctl -V`: https://pastebin.com/R4ykihLv
- `apache2ctl -S`: https://pastebin.com/JaEGQLgS
- `$ sudo grep -r "/var/www/html" /` (partial, I stopped it after almost 5 hours): https://pastebin.com/9iJyAH9J

Comment: Check `apachectl -V` to confirm the configuration files you are looking at are the proper ones.

Comment: I edited the question to contain the output of `apachectl -V` and `-S`

Comment: The /var/www/html is the value that it was compiled with, so it is the default.  You cannot change it.    If you set your DocumentRoot to another value it will use that value.

Comment: @Nic3500, It looks like you may be on to something. I checked three other apache servers I have, none of which use /var/www/html, all of which have documentroot configured per virtual host, and apache2ctl -S shows it as the main documentroot for all of them.

Comment: So the question is unsolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Nic3500 pointed out, the `/var/www/html` is the default value for the main DocumentRoot. Changing virtual host configurations *does not* affect this. However, adding a DocumentRoot directive to `apache.conf` does change it as reflected in the output of `apache2ctl -S`.

In other words, my main DocumentRoot was unconfigured and the default value was used until I explicitly defined it in a global configuration file.

Comment: Unsolved then...

Comment: Where is this apache.conf?

Answer (score 1):

In Debian/Ubuntu, the default virtual host file: **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** has the DocumentRoot **/var/www/html**.

I think the Main DocumentRoot reported by **apache2ctl -S** is same as the default DocumentRoot. The default DocumentRoot is either defined in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** or in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**. This is described in [How to Change Default Apache ‘DocumentRoot’ Directory in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/change-root-directory-of-apache-web-server/). So to change the Main DocumentRoot, you will need to edit **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**.

Comment: I've edited my question with more information about my configuration files. It isn't set in 000-default.conf in this case, and none of my conf files have that directory referenced in them..

Comment: To find out which virtual host is configured to use the DocumentRoot: /var/www/html, run the command: grep  "/var/www/html" /etc/apache2 -R

Comment: I have done that and it returns nothing; I grepped the whole disk drive searching for that string and it doesn't appear in any apache configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The **[DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot)** directive Apache's documentation is clear about its default value:

> Default: DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"

and **[Default](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Default)** means the value given by Apache when no one is specified anywhere:

> If the directive has a default value (i.e., if you omit it from your
> configuration entirely, the **Apache Web server will behave as though
> you set it to a particular value**)

And yes, I know **/usr/local/apache/htdocs** is different from your value **/var/www/html** but this is just a minor detail which depends on the linux distribution the Apache was built to.